# Pass not working within "Run Shell Script" of Shortcuts app

Tags: password, shortcut, copy-paste, shortcuts-app

I want to setup a shell script shortcut with the [Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts-mac/welcome/mac) app to copy a password to my clipboard. The script works fine when running it manually from the terminal, but it times out when running it from the Shortcuts app.

### Setup

Prerequisites for running the script are:

```bash
brew install pass
brew install pass-otp
brew install pinentry-mac
brew install choose-gui

echo "pinentry-program /opt/homebrew/bin/pinentry-mac" > .gnpug/gpg-agent.conf
killall gpg-agent
```

And you need at least one password in the password store. You can add one by running:

```bash
pass generate example.com
```

### The Script

```bash
prefix=${PASSWORD_STORE_DIR-~/.password-store}
password_files=( "$prefix"/**/*.gpg )
password_files=( "${password_files[@]#"$prefix"/}" )
password_files=( "${password_files[@]%.gpg}" )

password=$(printf '%s\n' "${password_files[@]}" | /opt/homebrew/bin/choose "$@")

[[ -n $password ]] || exit

plain=$(/opt/homebrew/bin/pass show ${password})
echo ${plain} | pbcopy
```

[image]

### The Issue

Running the script from within a shell manually works fine. The choose menu opens where I can select a password and it is succesfully copied to my clipboard.

But running the script from within the Shortcuts app doesn't work. The choose menu opens successfully, but after selecting a password, the script just runs infinitely without exiting.

My assumption is that it waits for a password input to decrypt the password file with GPG. When running the script manually, the Pinentry Mac UI opens to enter a password. Maybe this is broken from within the Shortcuts app.

Answer (score 1):

## Graphical Requirement?

Does any dependency of your script require access to the Window Manager or graphical session to work? If so, is Shortcuts running your script in the *current graphical session*?

The following approaches try to force the script to run within the current graphical session.

### Application Based

Try creating a stand alone application that runs your shell script. Get this application working consistently, then use Shortcuts.app to launch the resulting application.

If needed, the application can be ad-hoc code signed. It can also be  tested in isolation from Shortcuts.

To create an application, use Automator.app or Script Editor.app to run the script, using **do shell script**, and **Save as…** an app.

### Terminal Based

Alternatively, save your shell script as a text file with the extension `.command` and open this file using Shortcuts. This should launch Terminal.app and run the script.